# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module in using WebPack in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, webpack

I want to use WebPack to use some external library in my chrome extension.

Here is my package.json file:

```
  {
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.88.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "a11y-dialog": "^7.5.2"
  }
}
```

And here is my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    popup: './popup/popup.js',
    background: './background.js',
    bottom_button: './bottom_button.js',
    business_logic: './server/business_logic.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
};
```

I see that I can successfully run my build. However, when I try to use an external library in my business_logic.js file:

```
import A11yDialog from 'a11y-dialog'
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

My popup.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Extension</title>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>

  <style>
    body {
      width: 300px;
      height: 120px;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    input[type="text"] {
      width: 200px;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    button {
      padding: 5px 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="textInput" placeholder="Enter text">
  <button id="submitButton">Send</button>
  <div id="result">Hello world</div>


  <script src="../server/business_logic.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: You need `type="module"` in the `<script>` tag

Comment: After I added it, I receive an error.

popup.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: BusinessLogic is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (popup.js:8:7)